# Factoring a quadratic polynomial, $4T^{2}-48T+144$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

The question is asking me to factor the following polynomial to the simplest form. (without making it messy)
\begin{align*}
 & 4T^{2}-48T+144\\ 
\end{align*}
Here is how I do it but not sure which ending is the most appropriate.
\begin{align*}
 &  4T^{2}-48T+144\\ 
 &=4\left ( T^{2}-12T+36 \right ) \\ 
 &=4\left [ \left ( T^{2}-6T \right ) + \left ( -6T+36 \right )\right ] \\ 
 &=4\left [ T\left ( T-6 \right )-6\left (T-6  \right ) \right ] \\ 
 &=4\left ( T-6 \right )\left ( T-6 \right )
\end{align*} 
I know $4\left ( T-6 \right )\left ( T-6 \right )$ is equal to $4\left ( T-6 \right )^{2}$ 
but I don't know which one is simpler. I assume my answer is simpler as it has no power but the book answers $4\left ( T-6 \right )^{2}$. Any help is appreciated

Comment: The two notation are strictly equivalent, none is simpler than the other. $4(T-6)^2$ is cleaner I think.

Comment: When "completely factoring" it is often desired to collect like factors

Comment: @DavidP So the $4\left ( T-6 \right )^{2}$ is the answer?

Comment: @normal human, thank you for editing my tag. I apologize for it.

Comment: They both mean the same thing. Either one is fine.

Comment: @user153582 thank you

Comment: Which is simpler? $2^{20}$ or $2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2$?

Comment: It is sometimes useful to see multiple factors/roots at a glance. That said, no-one has suggested that $2^2(T-6)^2$ is simpler. Sometimes it is useful to see how many factors there are - whether we're dealing with a quadratic or cubic or quartic, for example. These things are contextual. [In more advanced work, the powers in a factorisation sometimes become significant in themselves eg ramification indices]